# LibreOffice Calc time formatting trouble

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, date-time, text-formatting

I'm calculating a time sheet with `LibreOffice` with this `SUM` column.

```
00:00
08:00
08:00
08:00
08:00
08:00
00:00
04:00:00 PM
```

The printing format of the bottom row is `Time 876613:37:46` but that's not how it's showing up. Does anybody know why? The interesting thing is when I highlight the cell I see `SUM=40:00:00` on the bottom bar.

Comment: Which format did you choose for the first seven rows? What happens if you remove direct formatting from the sum cell?

Comment: I chose the same formatting for the first seven cells and when I remove direct formatting it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Each input that you have (each row) is represented in `HH:MM` format. But you have to keep in mind that `LibreOffice.Calc` holds a number which it converts into the time format. Time in `LibreOffice.Calc` starts on `30 Dec 1899 at 00:00:00`. Therefore, when you type 8 hours you actually have `30 Dec 1899 08:00:00` which is equivalent to number `0.3(3)`.
This way, 5 rows with this value add up to `1.6(6)` which translates to `31 Dec 1899 16:00:00`.
If you convert this value into `HH:MM` you get `16:00`, the time of day of the provided date.
If you convert this value into `[HH]:MM` you get `40:00` because that's how much time has elapsed since time 0, `30 Dec 1899 00:00:00`.

With this in mind, in order to see the actual worked time, your `SUM` cell should have the format `[HH]:MM`or `[HH]:MM:SS` which is independent of the other formats.